# How do I put a flutter PageView inside a Listview?

Tags: flutter, viewport, flutter-listview, flutter-pageview

My goal is to have a Pageview horizontal scroll only for some widgets in my Listview. My expectation is, I can just put Pageview inside a Listview, but I got some kind of `error unbound height`. Which led me to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49765219/how-do-i-put-a-flutter-pageview-inside-a-column-or-row-i-get-the-error-below-wh), it solves the problem by containing Pageview inside a Container or Sizedbox. The solution did work for Column but doesn't work for Listview. Still got the same `error unbound height`.

Here is the code that I write

```dart
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: ListView(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24),
          children: [
            SomeWidget(),

            // Dropdown status
            SizedBox(height: 16),
            SomeWidget(),

            // The Pageview
            SizedBox(height: 16),
            Expanded(
              child: PageView(
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(height: 100, child: Container(color: Colors.red)),
                  Container(color: Colors.blue),
                  Container(color: Colors.yellow),
                  Container(color: Colors.amber),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: listview is not the same of column, column has bound height but list view does not. can i see the ui design of what you try to achieve?

Comment: @eamirho3ein I can't really show you the design, cause it's just some practice, and I don't really make any designs like Figma for this. But you can take a look at Lifesum as an example. Anyway, the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

PageView Requires size Expanded
while list view must know the size of its children
you can use this library
https://pub.dev/packages/expandable_page_view
which is know the size of screen then set it to the PageView

Comment: I think that's deprecated now, somehow itembuilder got call multiple times, cause me a lot of headache